# Horizontal scrolling with a fixed width in HTML CSS Javascript Angular JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have a horizontal banner. Inside the banner, I have 4 fixed elements. First element is a image / link. 2nd fixed element is suppose to be used for scrolling left. 3rd is a fixed width element which will have images ( number varies and clicking on first image will add another image element. 4th is another fixed element suppose to be used for scrolling right.

I did some basic searching on the internet and found few solutions but they are not working for me.

The width for elements to be used for navigation is fixed like 75px. The first element width is also fixed like 100px, 3 element which will have the images is calculated calc(100% - 250px).

I have used overflow-x:hidden for the third element.

I tried the scroll using the code document.getElement('.scroll').scrollLeft += 200;

This will work only when I define the width of that element like 1000px; when I make it fixed and hide the overflow, I am not able to see all the elements which are over flowing also the above code to scroll also did not work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I created a [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rAPDWd4ErpCY9U16H9HD) demonstrating scrolling a container of images.

First, I created a parent component that handles navigation and a image container component. Whenever the user clicks a button on the navigation, i am setting the transform CSS property to move the inner div by a number of pixels.

The outer div contains a fixed width set to 285px with overflow hidden.

**ImageContainer.js**

```
ctrl.$onChanges = function(changes) {
  console.log(changes);
  // set the image width of all images
  if (changes.imageSize) {
   ctrl.imageStyle = {width: changes.imageSize.currentValue + 'px'};
  }
  // update the scroll position
  if (changes.scrollPosition) {
     ctrl.scrollStyle = { transform: 'translateX(' + 
     changes.scrollPosition.currentValue + 'px)' };
  }

 }
```

**imageContainer.html**

```
<div class="flex fixed-image-container-width" >
  <div class="flex scrolling" ng-style="$ctrl.scrollStyle">
     <div class="item"  ng-repeat="item in $ctrl.items track by $index">
        <img ng-style="$ctrl.imageStyle"   ng-src="{{item}}"/>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the quick response. I am going through the example and implement in my page. I will get back if I face any issue.

Comment: One issue I am facing now is, the width of the container containing images is fixed, but when the left most button is clicked I am adding another image to the list, in this case, the width is increasing and going out of the screen. Not sure how to make sure it does not and stays fixed. Appreciate your help.